# Why is there a \o/ next to the candy amount when you have 42?

Tags: candy-box-2

I've noticed this happening to my candy amount:

```
You have 40 candies
You have 41 candies
You have 42 candies \o/
You have 43 candies
```

Why does that little "happy person" sprite appear when I have 42 candies? I've tried clicking on it, but nothing happens. Does this have any significance in-game? If so, how do you use it, and if not, then why is this happening?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From the [Candy Box 2 Wiki: Easter Eggs](http://candybox2.net/wiki/Easter_Eggs)

> One Easter Egg in the game is that when candy count reaches 42, The
>   Player ("\o/") appears beside the number for a brief period of time.
>   This is a reference to the Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy, where 42
>   is the answer to life, the universe and everything.
>
> When you get 1337 candies, the counter says "You have leet candies" in
>   place of the count of candies.

Comment: Ah, thanks! I was hoping that it was actually a hidden item or something. :) (I will accept this in 3 minutes when I can)

Comment: The question for that answer is actually: "What do you get if you multiply six by nine?" So there you go. The true meaning of life. Care for a waffle thin mint, Mr. Creosote?

Comment: @JohnDoeSanta 6*9 = 54 - The question was borked by the arrival of human beings on planet Earth... So we never discover the actual question.